# Why is the tangent vector this limit? (geometrically)

Tags: calculus, analysis

Let $f:I\to\mathbb R^2$ be a differentiable function, where $I\subset\mathbb R$ and $a\in I$. I would like to know why geometrically the tangent vector is $f'(a)=\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{f(a+t)-f(a)}{t}$.

[image]

Comment: It's the definition. Right hand side you have the difference quotient, which, when the limit goes to zero, IS the derivative.

Comment: @Fib1123 Yes but why does this definition make sense?

Comment: @Fib1123 in another words, why does this tangent agree with our intuitive idea of tangent? why does this touch the curve in this one point?

Comment: Try making $t$ progressively smaller in your picture. What do you notice?

Comment: It's not just a line that touches the graph at the point but the limit of the secant line joining the two points.

Comment: @Fib1123 yes, the problem is, the secant line as is depicted in the picture is the vector $f(a+t)-f(a)$. For me the limit should be $\lim_{t\to 0} f(a+t)-f(a)$ instead of $\lim_{t\to 0} f(a+t)-f(a)/t$

Comment: @user42912 You're forgetting what *the tangent* is: sine divided by cosine. If you draw an axis plane, you'll see easier that $\;f(x+t)-f(t)\;$ is the sine (the vertical length) of the angle that in the limit will be the derivative, and $\;t\;$ gives you the cosine = the horizontal length.

Comment: @DonAntonio thank you for your comment. I didn't understand how to sketch this axis plane.

Comment: @user42912 This definitely isn't a bad question, people tend not to get questions on intuition, but please feel free to continue asking